# How to install pcsx2 in Linux Mint 17.3?

Tags: linux-mint

I am trying to install PS2 emulator `pcsx2` in Linux Mint 17.3. However, when I try it after adding a ppa it gives me:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pcsx2:i386 : Depends: libegl1-mesa:i386 (>= 7.8.1) or
                       libegl1-x11:i386
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install that dependecies `sudo apt-get install libegl1-mesa:i386`
 I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libegl1-mesa:i386 : Depends: libgbm1:i386 (>= 7.11~1) but it is not         going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And finaly, when I try to install that last dependency I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgbm1:i386 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

What is the problem here? Is this lib installed or not? I have multiarch installed. Could this be the problem because this dependency isn't multiarch compatible? If Mint is using repos from Ubuntu why is this working in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is due to mesa-dri broken packages you can try one by one
>   commands on terminal to fix this issues.

```
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libgl1-mesa-dri
$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libgl1-mesa
$ sudo dpkg --purge --force-all libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-all libgl1-mesa-dri
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-all libgl1-mesa-glx
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-all libglapi-mesa:i386
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-all libgl1-mesa-dri:i386
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-all libgl1-mesa-dev
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-all libqt4-opengl-dev
$ sudo dpkg -r --force-all libgl1-mesa-dri
$ sudo apt-get -f install
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install pcsx2
```

After that PCSX2 configuration and installations steps are according to as shown in [tutorial](http://www.techbrown.com/pcsx2-install-setup-configuration-ubuntu-linux-mint.shtml).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it later, but could you please explain what those commands do? I undersand you remove these libs and what then? Don't they get installed again? Why is not a new version updated without removing the old one?

Comment: In Ubuntu 16.04 and Mint 18 no dependency hell anymore. Just install it like this: 
`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gregory-hainaut/pcsx2.official.ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pcsx2`

Answer (score 2):

As is explained [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=179533) try with

```
sudo apt-get install libwayland-egl1-mesa-lts-vivid:i386 libegl1-mesa-lts-vivid:i386
```